# How to replace dict values with new values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
the 117
to 77
. 77
, 56
a 47
is 46
and 41
that 39
...
```

I wanted to divide each number in the dictionary by the max value.. so I did this:

```
count_values = (count.values())
newValues = [x / max(count_values) for x in count_values]
```

I want to replace the values in the dictionary with newValues.

How can I do that?

Comment: Iterate over the keys, then reassign the value to the normalized value at each key

Comment: When you say "replace the values", do you mean that you have to change them in the original dictionary (maybe because someone else has a reference to it), or just that you need to end up with a dictionary with the normalized values (and don't care whether it's the same one or a new one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using dictionary comprehension.

```
old_values = {'the': 117, 'to': 77, '.': 77, ',': 56, 'a': 46, 'is': 46, 'and': 41, 'that': 39}
m = max(old_values.values())
new_values = {k: v / m for k, v in old_values.items()}
```

This produces a dictionary like this:

```
{'the': 1.0, 
 'to': 0.6581196581196581, 
 '.': 0.6581196581196581, 
 ',': 0.47863247863247865, 
 'a': 0.39316239316239315, 
 'is': 0.39316239316239315, 
 'and': 0.3504273504273504, 
 'that': 0.3333333333333333}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably don't want to compute `max(count_values)` over and over for each element, so do that once up-front:

```
max_value = max(count.values())
```

Now, if you actually need to modify the dict in-place, do it like this:

```
for key in count:
   count[key] /= max_value
```

However, if you don't need to do that, it's usually cleaner to make a new dict via a comprehension, as in [Haleemur Ali's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49269969/908494):

```
count = {key: value / max_value for key, value in count.items()}
```